# Reliable 3rd-party source for downloading softwares for Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, software

I am a new MacBook user. I am thinking about http://www.filehippo.com/mac for downloading DMGs. Does it have any security/virus issue? If there are other sources then please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable place for downloads for Mac is the [App Store](http://store.apple.com/us).

It is already installed on your Mac (just click on the top left Apple icon)

Also, you do not have to go to http://www.filehippo.com/mac to get Firefox or Chrome.

If not available at App Store, I usually go directly to the Developer web site to get the download.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Homebrew Cask](http://caskroom.io/) for non-cli software and [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for cli-software. It makes installing, updating and removing software much much easier.